# VALUE ERROR in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

My formula below has an error.

If there is no *BX17* available in cell `Z58` it should return `DDR` but instead I just get a `#Value` 
Any help on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

```
=IF(V58<=0,IF(W58="DDR",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("*BX17*",Z58),"DDR"),"BX18","DDR"),"DDR"),0)
```

Comment: Why don't you replace `SEARCH()` with `IF(Z58<>"BX17","DDR","")`?

Comment: Thanks for looking, its searching BX17 in a cell that contains a whole string of number eg bx1712345

Answer (score 1):

You get this error due of the inner `IF()`.

When `Z58` contains "BX17" `IFERROR()` returns 1 (as number), otherwise it returns "DDR".

When `Z58` contains "BX17" the `IF()` around it returns "BX18", otherwise it returns the `#VALUE`-error.

`IF()` interprets the returning 1 as `TRUE` and would interpret 0 as `FALSE`. But it can't interpret the string "DDR" which is returned.